# Data allocated by malloc() is not zero

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management

I use 'malloc()' to allocate memory for a structure in C language. Part of the structure is as below:

```
struct f2fs_sb_info {
    struct f2fs_fsck *fsck;
    struct f2fs_super_block *raw_super;
    struct f2fs_nm_info *nm_info;
    struct f2fs_sm_info *sm_info;
    struct f2fs_checkpoint *ckpt;
};
```

I find that the value of `raw_super` is always zero, while the value of `ckpt` is always `0x40000050`.

I know that `malloc()` will not initialize the allocated memory. So the allocated memory should has random value. But the value of `ckpt` is always `0x40000050` and does not change every time I run the program. Why?

Comment: I'm not clear about the code you posted. You have a single `{` and no closing brace. When you say the value of `ckpt` do you mean the pointer itself or some value inside the struct (which I don't know about because you haven't given the definitions of the structures).

Comment: What do you do before and after `malloc`ing?

Comment: "indeterminate", not "random".

Answer (score 7):

Allocated memory can store *any value* after allocation, but it does not have to be *random* - allocation is not random generator at all.

Answer (score 5):

Think of this as a mere intriguing peculiarity.

An uninitialised variable (such as your structure elements following a memory allocation for your structure) can take any value. Such a value is said to be *indeterminate*. The C standard does not require that they are initialised in any way. Note that the behaviour on reading such a variable (other than an `unsigned char`) is *undefined* since an uninitialised value could be a trap representation.

Comment: Thank you. What the value of 'ckpt' would be, if the structure is a local variable rather than memory allocated by malloc()? In such a situation, It will not cause a trap.

Answer (score 4):

> Why?

Because the value is indeterminate. And accessing an indeterminate value has undefined behaviour (it wouldn't be UB if the type had been `unsigned char` as pointed out by Bathsheba).

> But the value of 'ckpt' is always ... and does not change

Note that even though it has not changed so far, there are no guarantees that it would never change. This sort of value/output is called "garbage".

Have you tried another compiler? That could change the value. Have you tried modifying an unrelated part of the program? That could change it. Have you tried to imagine butterflies while you run the program? There is no guarantee that wouldn't change the value, though you might need a mind-reading adapter for that to happpen. None of the above are guaranteed to change the value either.

Comment: I'm feeling extra pedantic today: It's UB only if the type is not an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Bathsheba that's very useful extra information. The type is a pointer in this case, so the access is UB in this case. The context I meant to imply wasn't explicit enough.

Answer (score 1):

Programmed algorithms are almost always deterministic, they act always the same way, and `malloc` memory selection got such an algorithm.

`malloc` generally allocates some memory pool at runtime start and then use memory taken from this pool to serve the requests (it can enlarge the pool of preallocated memory if the requests are for very large amount of memory, or reduce it if the user frees a lot of memory).

If in your code you allocate some memory (that `malloc` take from the pool), initialize it then release it after use, and then reallocate it again in the same sequence, the probability that the you will get the same piece of memory with inside the same data it was initialized before is very high. This can be the reason of your finding.

You may make a try using a fake allocation in another point, maybe as first allocation of your program, and check if the value is still the same...

Anyway this eventual peculiarity have to be connected to the allocation chain in your code, not to the system memory, that because of its more intense use have a very low probability to repeat casual data in allocated sets.

And of course this is an **UB**...

Comment: Note that the allocation and release could have been in the run-time startup code, outside the user program's control, but the startup code is also determinsitic.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You're right also runtime functions use `malloc`. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 0):

Though many things have already been pointed out, the following code demonstrates that you really cannot rely neither on the value being always the same nor being always different. It is not guaranteed that allocated memory is initialized, neither with `0`-values, nor with randomized values. The result of `malloc` will simply point to an address out of a (huge) memory block, called the heap; At application startup, the operating system provides a heap to the application, but there is no guarantee that the operating system will always give you the same portion of the system's memory as your application's heap (it may be, but it does not have to be):

Consider the following program, which mallocs the same structure 3 trimes

```
struct myTestStruct {
    char* p1;
    char* p2;
    char* p3;
    char* p4;
    char* pToBeObserved;
};

int main()
{
    struct myTestStruct *myStructs[10];

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        myStructs[i] = (struct myTestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(myTestStruct));

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: %p\n", i, (void*)myStructs[i]->pToBeObserved);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output when running this program once is the following:

```
0'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x636f6c5f6b636f6c
1'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x0
2'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x0
3'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x202020202020202
4'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x7fff77dd30c8
5'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x100200380
6'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x0
7'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x0
8'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x100058568
9'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0xc
```

It shows that when you reserve memory several times in the same program execution, the value of `pToBeObserved` actually changes (though this is not guaranteed that it changes). The reason is, that consecutive calls to `malloc` point to different portions of the heap, and so the chance that `pToBeObserved` "views" a different value is higher;

If you start the program again and again, it *may* be the case that at least the first `malloc` will point to the same portion of the heap, and it *may* be that the operating system has assigned the same portion of system memory to your application:

```
Run1: 0'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x636f6c5f6b636f6c
Run3: 0'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x636f6c5f6b636f6c
Run4: 0'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x636f6c5f6b636f6c
Run5: 0'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x636f6c5f6b636f6c
Run6: 0'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x636f6c5f6b636f6c
```

but at an arbitrary run (run 7 in my test), the value suddenly changes:

```
Run7: 0'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x0
```

Further, if during the runs, I change the `struct` and add a member before `pToBeObserved`, then the next run always yielded a different value in my tests:

```
Run1: 0'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x636f6c5f6b636f6c

struct myTestStruct {
    char added;
    char* p1;
    char* p2;
    char* p3;
    char* p4;
    char* pToBeObserved;
};

Next run: 0'th instance; value of pToBeObserved: 0x6f5f687469775f6b
```

This example shows again that you just get a pointer somewhere in the heap, and if you change the memory layout of your struct (by adding a member), then member `pToBeObserved` will view a different portion of the (uninitialized) heap memory.